# aggregating json fields

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, set-returning-functions

I have a table that holds JSON data. In a query with a `GROUP BY` clause, I'd like to get an array of all of the JSON field names in the result set.

I tried a query like this:

```
SELECT array_agg(jsonb_object_keys(data)) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY some_id 
WHERE some_id = 3
```

For an input data like

```
some_id | data
--------|---------------
3       | {"foo": "bar"}
4       | {"baz": 3}
3       | {"bar": 4}
```

I'd like to receive:

```
array_agg
--------------
{'foo', 'bar'}
```

But it returns an error: `ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set`

It seems like I need to somehow convert `setof text`, which is what `jsonb_object_keys` returns, into `array` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you can't use a set returning in the `SELECT` list. You need to put it into the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT array_agg(t.k) 
FROM table tbl, jsonb_object_keys(tbl.data) as t(k) 
WHERE tbl.some_id = 3
GROUP BY tbl.some_id;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works now - I wanted to edit your typos in line 2 (t -> tbl, a -> as) but it's less than 6 characters so SO won't let me